# merging / combining kdd2009 dataset using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge KDD 2009 dataset as follow as you can see there are 4 dataframes

```
df_a = pd.read_table( 'orange_large_train.data.chunk1')

df_b = pd.read_table('orange_large_train.data.chunk2')

df_c = pd.read_table( 'orange_large_train.data.chunk3')

df_d = pd.read_table('orange_large_train.data.chunk4')

frames = [df1, df2, df3,df4, df5 ]

orange_kdd_data = pd.concat(frames)
```

I got the following error, can anyone help?

```
C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy)
   4909         raise AssertionError("Concatenating join units along axis0")
   4910 
-> 4911     empty_dtype, upcasted_na = get_empty_dtype_and_na(join_units)
   4912 
   4913     to_concat = [ju.get_reindexed_values(empty_dtype=empty_dtype,

C:\Users\User\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get_empty_dtype_and_na(join_units)
   4898         return np.dtype('m8[ns]'), tslib.iNaT
   4899     else:  # pragma
-> 4900         raise AssertionError("invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype")
   4901 
   4902 

AssertionError: invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype
```

Comment: This error can occur when Pandas encounters dtypes it does not know how to upcast. We might be able to be more specific if we see `[df.info() for df in frames]`. That will show us the dtypes of all the columns in each DataFrame.

Comment: By the way, you are not merging but appending.